# not able to display data through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a piece of code in ajax through which i am trying to print values

```
success: function(returndata) {
    $('#first').html("<div id='first' class='progress-bar progress-bar-primary' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='22' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: "+ returndata[0] +"%;>"+ returndata[0] +"%'</div>");
    }
```

I am getting value of `returndata[0]` and it is getting printed in first part i.e `style='width: "+ returndata[0] +"` but i am not getting value in second part i.e `+ returndata[0] +`

it should adjust background color width and along with it should print a number over it like this 
[image]

but at present only the width of the color is coming properly but no digit over it. it is looking like this

[image]

can anyone please tell where i am going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have accidentally forgot to close the style tag.

```
style='width: "+ returndata[0] +"%>'//Missing aposthrophe
```

This code should work fine:

```
 success: function(returndata) {
    $('#first').html("<div id='first' class='progress-bar progress-bar-primary' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='22' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: "+ returndata[0] +"%;'>"+ returndata[0] +"%'</div>");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```js
   
var returndata=[];
returndata.push(40);

$('#first').html('<div id="first" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary"      role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="22" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:'+returndata[0]+'%;">'+returndata[0]+'</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="first">
  
  </div>
```